# JSON not serialising properly... I think?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

I have a Node.js project that uses socket.io. In it, I try sending an object from the client to the server like this:

```
socket.send(JSON.stringify({'type':'msg','message':'test'}));
```

When it arrives on the server, I call `JSON.parse` on it, and check if `object.type == 'msg'`. When I run the code and call `console.log(object.type)` it returns `"msg"`, but `object.type == 'msg'` returns false. What's going on here?

EDIT:

The relevant part of the code that is failing is:

```
client.on('message', function(message, client){
    var envelope = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(envelope.type);
    if(envelope.type == "msg") { console.log("yay!"); }
}
```

Whenever a message comes in, `msg` is printed, but not `yay!`.

Comment: Can you show us some of your server code? Right now I can't think of any reason why this would fail.

Comment: You said "...it returns msg,...", shouldn't it *return an object with msg* instead?

Comment: Try to inject `console.log(message);` as the first line of the function. Also, check `typeof envelope.type` if it doesn't read a string, then that will explain why the comparison fails.

Comment: @Martin He's using `==` so the type doesn't matter here, what I suspect is that Node swallows the second `log()` call, I had such issues in the past.

Comment: @Ivo The problem is that none of the code after the second console.log call is called either, and other double logs have worked before.

Comment: Just for the heck of it, right after you parse the message, do a `console.log(envelope.type.length)`. I had a problem similar to this once where I had a rogue null character at the beginning of my string.

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: i'm getting true here: https://c9.io/aoviedo/so-question-4914724

Comment: Curious if you ever solved this issue.

Comment: @ElliotNelson Can't say that I have, I'd assume it was a Node bug at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try using non-literals as keys in your JSON message? I'm building a small chat server to explore socket.io, using JSON messages. Here's my relevant code:

Client-side:

```
var jsonMsg = {
      action: 'SEND',
      body: msg,
      name: name.val()
    };
socket.send(JSON.stringify(jsonMsg));
```

Please note that both msg and name.val() are string values, grabbed from the corresponding input fields.

Server-side:

```
client.on('message', function(m, c) {
  // parse message
  var msg = json.parse(m);

  switch (msg.action) {
    case 'SEND':
      // send message to channel
      var broadCast = {
        posted: date.toReadableDate(new Date(), 'timestamp'),
        message: msg.body,
        name: msg.name
      };
      socket.broadcast(json.stringify(broadCast));
      break;
  }
});
```

Note: `toReadableDate` is a custom prototype method.

The message is recieved correctly on the server- and on the client-side as broadcast.

Comment: It wouldn't make a difference, the keys are parsed by the client, so whether or not they're (properly) encoded or not shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Which json serialization library are you using? My example uses [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), maybe thats the caveat.

Comment: V8 on both sides. Using a separate JSON library would be inefficient.

Comment: Have you tried using json2.js on both ends? I can't see any other sources for your problem (except for some null chars slipping in, but that should really not happen).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a node bug? I've just tried it in 0.5.0-pre and it works fine in the limited context.

```
> message = JSON.stringify({'type':'msg','message':'test'})
'{"type":"msg","message":"test"}'
>     var envelope = JSON.parse(message);
>     console.log(envelope.type);
msg
>     if(envelope.type == "msg") { console.log("yay!"); }
yay!
```

Other options might be an encoding issue (looks like "msg" on the terminal but isn't strictly those characters in the string?)

Answer (score -1):

Your message must be in the format '{"type":"msg"}'.